# DestroyImmediate() Not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

making a small game for my own enjoyment, and have a button which i want to use to cancel the audio being played.

The audio is created in this method:

```
public void PlaySound(AudioClip[] audioClip )
{
    int random = Random.Range(0, audioClip.Length);
    Ed = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    AudioClip myNew;
    myNew = audioClip[random];
    Ed.clip = myNew;
    Ed.Play();
}
```

And i'm trying to destroy in this one:

```
public void StopPlayBack()
{
    AudioSource myAudio;

    myAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    Debug.Log("My Audio is 1 :" + myAudio);
    if (myAudio != null)
    {
        DestroyImmediate(myAudio);
        Debug.Log("My Audio is NOT null");
        Debug.Log("My Audio is 2 :" + myAudio);
    }
    else if ( myAudio == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("My Audio is null");
    }
    Debug.Log("My Audio is 3 :" + myAudio);

}
}
```

Sometime the audio will be destroyed, and sometime I have to click the button twice. The Debug logs will always show the same result however, whether it is destroyed or not. ( ie After the destroy method, the audioSource is null) Not sure why it sometimes works and sometimes does not?

Comment: Never use "DestroyImmediate".  (It's only for extremely unusual cases in unusual, advanced use of Unity during development testing - you absolutely should not use it as it will break.)  If you're a hobbyist programmer, there are many confusing things like this in Unity.  For example, you constantly see code examples using "coroutines". In fact, you should never use coroutines - just use "Invoke" (or perhaps "InvokeRepeating") for simple timers in Unity.  Another example is quaternions.  Never use them - they should not even be mentioned in the manual. You just use "Rotate", trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DestroyImmediate` is for use in editor code. It even says so in the [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html). At runtime, `Destroy` should be used instead.

A few words of advice: you don't need the temporary `AudioClip` variable in the play method.  You could change it to:

```
public void PlaySound(AudioClip[] audioClip )
{
    int random = Random.Range(0, audioClip.Length);
    Ed = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    Ed.clip = audioClip[random];
    Ed.Play();
}
```

Also, you shouldn't really be adding an audio source *every time* you want to play a clip. Make one `AudioSource` and add it to the `Start` function and then reuse it throughout your code. Like this:

```
private AudioSource audioSource;

public void Start()
{
    audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
}

public void PlaySound(AudioClip[] audioClip )
{
    int random = Random.Range(0, audioClip.Length);
    audioSource.clip = audioClip[random];
    audioSource.Play();
}
```

This way you can stop playback by having:

```
public void StopPlayBack()
{
    audioSource.Stop()    
}
```

Now when you call `PlaySound` it will play a random clip from the `audioClip` array that is passed and you can stop the sound by calling `StopPlayBack`. That is the correct way to start and stop audio but if you want to actually remove the `AudioSource` for some reason still then use:

```
public void StopPlayBack()
{
    Destroy(audioSource);    
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for the advise, really appreciate it!